# tikz Plotting the complex logarithm

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I would like to plot the complex logarithm (imaginary part) which is defined as follows:

ln(z) = ln(r) + i * arg(z)

This should look like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Riemann_surface_log.svg). However, I have no experience with 3 dimensional/complex tikz plots and do not know the notation to plot this function properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pgfplots` cannot deal with complex coordinates out of the box. However, in this case it is not really necessary either, I think. You wish to depict a mapping \mathds{C}\to\mathds{C}, which his is not possible with a 3d plot, yet your target outcome seems to be a 3d plot. To produce something of the sort, you can just use your own coordinates

```
({x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)},{ln(x)+y})
```

where `x` is the radius and `y` is the phase. Now there is a problem in that we only have 3 coordinates at our disposal. Having used up two for the domain, we need to use a projection. I do not know what projection you use in the image you use, but the following seems to come close:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm,height=14cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,view={-50}{12},
    colormap={adopted}{rgb255(0cm)=(151,0,250);
    rgb255(1cm)=(219,0,70);rgb255(2cm)=(186,255,60)},
    z buffer=sort,zmin=-3.5*pi]
\addplot3 [surf,domain=0.001:4,domain y=-3*pi:3*pi,samples=25,samples y=109]
({x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)},{ln(x)+y});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using different angles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm,height=14cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,view={70}{20},
    colormap={adopted}{rgb255(0cm)=(151,0,250);
    rgb255(1cm)=(219,0,70);rgb255(2cm)=(186,255,60)},
    z buffer=sort,zmin=-3.5*pi]
\addplot3 [surf,domain=0.001:4,domain y=-3*pi:3*pi,samples=25,samples y=109]
({x*cos(y)},{x*sin(y)},{ln(x)+y});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use another projection, this can be built in, too.

Comment: If you run this code, compiling with `lualatex` speeds it up quite a bit.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the meaning of `ln(x)+y` in this context. Logarithm of a complex number with modulus $x$ and phase $y$ is $\ln(x)+iy$. One could, for example, plot modulus of the logarithm, which is $\sqrt{\ln(x)^2+y^2}$, or phase of the logarithm, which is something like $\arctan\frac y{\ln(x)}$, whereas $\ln(x)+y$ is the sum of the real and imaginary part of the logarithm.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, as I wrote, a mapping \mathds{C}\to\mathds{C} cannot be depicted in a 3d plot, so we need a projection. As I said, I just chose some that seems to get close to the OP's target output. There are alternatives.